# Get index path of particular elements from a array in flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter

I have a array of workout list. which has body parts name and the exercise list for the same body part. I want to get the index path of particular body part . let cosider the following example . Lets say i want to get the indexpath of "Arm". How to do this can anybody help me ?

```
    WorkoutModel(bodyPart: "Chest", excercise: [
      'Cable Cross-Over',
      'Push-Ups',
      'Suspended Push-Up',
      ' Incline Dumbbell Bench Press',
      'Barbell Bench Press',
      'Close-Grip Bench Press',
      'Dip',
      ' Seated Pec Deck Machine'
    ]),
    WorkoutModel(bodyPart: "Back", excercise: [
      'Resistance band pull apart',
      'Quadruped dumbbell row',
      'Lat pulldown',
      'Wide dumbbell row',
      'Barbell deadlift',
      'Hyperextension',
      'Good morning',
      'Single-arm dumbbell row',
    ]),
    WorkoutModel(bodyPart: "Arm", excercise: [
      "Kickboxing punches ",
      "Rolling pushups ",
      "Side plank ",
      "Superman",
      "Plank sidewalk ",
      "Bicep curls to push press",
      "Tricep dips",
      "Arm circles"
    ]),
    WorkoutModel(bodyPart: "Abdominal", excercise: [
      'Mountain climber',
      'Reverse crunch',
      'Grounded Russian twist',
      'Dead bug',
      'Leg raise',
      'Abs roll-out',
      'Bird-dog',
      'Hanging knee raise',
    ]),
    WorkoutModel(bodyPart: "Shoulder", excercise: [
      'Barbell Overhead Shoulder Press',
      'Seated Dumbbell Shoulder Press',
      'Front Raise',
      'Reverse Pec Deck Fly',
      'Bent-Over Dumbbell Lateral Raise',
      'Dumbbell Lateral Raise',
      'Push Press',
      'Reverse Cable Crossover',
    ]),
    WorkoutModel(bodyPart: "Leg", excercise: [
      "Front Squat ",
      'Bulgarian Split Squat',
      'Romanian Deadlift',
      'Squat',
      'Dumbbell Stepup',
      'Deadlift',
      'Swiss Ball Leg Curl',
      'Single-Leg Romanian Deadlift',

    ]),


  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = workoutModels
      .indexWhere((workoutModel) => workoutModel.bodyPart == "Arm");
```

or

```
int index = workoutModels
      .indexWhere((workoutModel) => workoutModel.bodyPart.compareTo("Arm") == 0);
```

Reference:

[indexWhere method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
List<String> things = [
  "Kickboxing punches ",
  "Rolling pushups ",
  "Side plank ",
  "Superman",
  "Plank sidewalk ",
  "Bicep curls to push press",
  "Tricep dips",
  "Arm circles"
];
    print(things.indexWhere((s) => s.startsWith('Arm'))); // 7
```

Answer (score 1):

you can user indexOf to find the index , in the where to find the element in lits

list is list of your WorkoutModel

```
list.indexOf(list. firstWhere((e)=> e.bodyPart == 'Arm',orElse: () => null ))
```